# Using a HTTP_PROXY present on another machine

Tags: ssh, http-proxy

I am sudo on computer A which has SSH access to computer B. A does not have internet access and can only access B.

B accesses the internet via an HTTP_PROXY.
The HTTP_PROXY for B cannot be used for A (some IP address filters).

How can i use SSH + something else to make use of B's HTTP_PROXY for A?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH port forwarding — e.g., if the proxy address:port is proxy.example.com:3128, then run on the computer A:

```
ssh -L 3128:proxy.example.com:3128 B
```

After doing this, use `localhost:3128` as HTTP proxy on A. You do not even need root access on A or B to do this (however, the admin of B could disable or limit port forwarding using the `AllowTcpForwarding` or `PermitOpen` options in `sshd_config`).

Add the `-N` option if you want to use this instance of `ssh` just for port forwarding.